# Which statistical test to perform for two identical experiments across different conditions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have two identical experiments. Each experiment have gene expressions for 12 samples with different conditions: untreated. Dosage 50. 100. 200.

I want to prove that these two experiments are identical or replicable. I can do two sample t tests across each conditions but will have 4 p-Values then. What’s a good test with a single p-value?

Answer (score 3):

Stack the two datasets into one, and add a factor `exper` that codifies which experiment each observation is from. Fit a model with formula `response - exper + Dosage`. Then look at the anova test of`exper`.

But really, if the objective is to show the experiments are the same, failing to find a significant difference does not accomplish that. Instead, you should do an equivalence test based on a defensible threshold for how big a difference in mean response would still be considered "the same." That entails using the two one-sided test (TOST) procedure for equivalence of `exper` means.

Comment: Would the first method works if I have three replicates for each dosage?

Comment: Yes. And the second par. isn't a different method, it can be used with the same setup. You do two one-sided t tests. For the threshold delta, you have equivalence if you can show that the difference is BOTH statistically less than delta and statistically greater than -delta, or equivalently that the (1-2alpha) CI for the difference lies entirely within (-delta, delta).

Comment: Thank you so much! So I have the data frame ready with columns: Gene, Dosage, Value (numeric), Experiment. So the formula in R would be aov(Value ~ Experiment + Dosage)? Then to get p-value I do, summary(model)? I'm working on your no. 2 now, thanks again!